# Как заставить mysql дублировать данные?

Tags: mysql, sql

Делаю следующий запрос:

```
(SELECT newsId FROM news WHERE newsId = 2)
UNION
(SELECT newsId FROM news WHERE newsId = 1)
```

и ожидаемо получаю:

```
[
  {
    "newsId": 2
  },
  {
    "newsId": 1
  }
]
```

Но если я меняю запрос следующим образом:

```
(SELECT newsId FROM news WHERE newsId = 1)
UNION
(SELECT newsId FROM news WHERE newsId = 1)
```

то я получаю:

```
[
  {
    "newsId": 1
  }
]
```

а мне надо:

```
[
  {
    "newsId": 1
  },
  {
    "newsId": 1
  }
]
```

Могу я каким-то образом изменить запрос, чтобы получить необходимые данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вывода всех данных используйте UNION ALL

Answer (score 3):

Оператор `UNION` при объединении удаляет повторяющиеся записи из результирующего набора. Чтобы этого избежать, используйте `UNION ALL`, тогда все дубликаты будут сохранены.